# Unable to get a specific value to another function

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am working to make logic circuit using Gates and multiplexar using javascript and GoJS. I want to fetch a particular input port value and use it in another function

```
      var multiplexarTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",  { width: 50, height: 80, margin: 4, 
      fill: "lightgray",  stroke: "darkslategray", strokeWidth: 2 
      }), 
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in1", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.2) }),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in2", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.4) }),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in3", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.6) }),  
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in4", alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0.8) }),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in5", alignment: new go.Spot(0.3, 1) }),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(true),
        { portId: "in6", alignment: new go.Spot(0.65, 1) }),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", portStyle(false),
        { portId: "out", alignment: new go.Spot(1, 0.5) }) 
       )
```

As in this example I want to fetch particularly in1 and use it in another function. In the same manner I want to get in2,in3,in4 also and use it in another function but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Node.findPort`: https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#findPort

```js
var in2 = someNode.findPort('in2');
```

Comment: I need to get the value of that port so I used   node.findPort('in2').value to get thevalue entered to the port but it returned undefined